# How to pass an entire map

Tags: java, dictionary, getter, treemap

got another issue.

Im trying to send an entire Map of objects and their associated keys so that it can be accessed from another class. The method I am using does not work, as I tried to use the same method that is used to pass an array list, but it does not work for a Map.

what would be the correct way of doing it?

this is what I have tried

```
public Map <Integer, Employee> getAllEmps()
{ 
     return (Map <Integer, Employee>) ;
}
```

and this is how I have declared it (the actual map itself)

```
private static  Map <Integer, Employee> employeeMap = new TreeMap<Integer,Employee>();
```

Comment: you should be returning `employeeMap` instead of returning an empty typecast

Comment: Doesn't the compiler tell you what is wrong? What error message is it giving you?

Comment: I'm curious, what book/resources are you using to study Java, the language itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return the variable itself:

```
public Map <Integer, Employee> getAllEmps()
{ 
     return employeeMap;
}
```

Which would allow anyone to modify the contnent of the map.

To prevent modification, you can return an unmodifiableMap:

```
public Map <Integer, Employee> getAllEmps()
{ 
     return Collections.unmodifiableMap(employeeMap);
}
```

Alternatively, you can return a copy:

```
public Map <Integer, Employee> getAllEmps()
{ 
     return new TreeMap<Integer,Employee>(employeeMap);
}
```

Comment: I have made the method in the MainDriver class and I want to access it from the other class. this line of code does not seem to work, how would I do it correctly

theEmployeeMap = MainDriver.getAllEmps();

Answer (score 2):

You have to return the map instance, not the type.

```
public Class SomeClass{
     private static Map<Integer,Employee> employeeMap=...;

    //Other methods 


   public Map <Integer, Employee> getAllEmps()
  { 
      return employeeMap ;
  }
}
```

If you want only the employees (with no keys) you can add another method

```
 public Collection<Employee> getEmployees(){

     return employeeMap.values();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try passing the variable itself and have the map as a member variable?

```
private Map <Integer, Employee> employeeMap = new Map <Integer, Employee>();    
public Map <Integer, Employee> getAllEmps()
{ 
     return employeeMap;
}
```

Comment: new TreeMap<Integer,Employee>()

Answer (score 0):

Your getAllMaps () function needs to actually return a map; do you mean it to return the static employeeMap?

Comment: Oh hello again Dave
Nah, I just want to return a map.

Comment: I have made the method in the MainDriver class and I want to access it from the other class. this line of code does not seem to work, how would I do it correctly. I have obviously declared theEmployeeMap  

theEmployeeMap = MainDriver.getAllEmps();

Comment: @Binyomin That syntax would imply a static method, not an instance method.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me.
its okay I declared it in the constructor rather then in the program itself so it wanted to be declared    as in: int i;
Im as little over tired:)